# some Persian numbers look broken (seven and four)

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

I almost have this issue with all newly installed distros.
some Persian numbers look so weird. like seven and three.
This is how '7' looks like in Persian:

[image: seven]

In my Kubuntu 23.04 machine (Broken Seven that looks like an English seven upside-down):

[image: Broken Seven Thank looks like an English seven upside-down]

'4' is also looks odd but more acceptable, Here is how '4' looks like in Persian (normal four):

[image: normal four]

And this is the system font (Broken four kinda looks like a stylish 3!):

[image: Broken four kinda looks like a stylish 3!]

other numbers looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to partially fix the issue by installing these packages:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-extra fonts-cantarell fonts-dejavu fonts-farsiweb fonts-freefarsi fonts-freefont-ttf
```

then rebuild font cache:

```bash
rm -fr /home/ubuntu/.cache/fontconfig
fc-cache -f -v
```

then reboot the machine:

```bash
reboot
```

#### What Got fixed

Firefox Browser, KDE text inputs, Dolphin and other apps (qt, gtk, etc) plus the `hack` font in system settings but not in Konsole and Kate (look at the screenshot below)

[image: system settings]
This is really confusing maybe there are still some cache that must be removed. IDK.
[image]
Firefox now works fine

#### what still has issues

Konsole and Kate

#### workarounds

If somehow the issue with these two softwares presists then use these workarounds:

For fixing the konsole maually change the font from profile settings to `dejavu sans mono`.

For Kate look at the @gunnar-hjalmarsson 's answer (Thanks Gunnar)
Go to `~/.config/katerc` and change this line:

`Font=Hack,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0`

to

`Font=dejavu sans mono,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: I became curious, and the thing is that Hack is the default monospace font in KDE. So an alternative way to fix it would have been to 1. replace Hack with DejaVu Sans Mono in System Settings, 2. remove the konsolerc and katerc files. Then the customized monospace font for KDE would have been applied next time you opened Kate or Konsole.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an arabic font installed which is rendering the numbers in arabic. You can install a persian font and set your program to use that font instead. Also your keyboard might be configured to output arabic letters, there is a distinct unicode symbol for ۴ vs ٤

[image]

Comment: Hello, My keyboard layout is set correctly to Persian in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the default font used by Kate is Hack, which I think causes your issue. I suggest that you change it by opening the `~/.config/katerc` file for editing and changing this line:

```
Font=Hack,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

to

```
Font=Noto Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```